# Parameter and Error Checking in C

Tags: c

First off, I'll explain that I'm very new at C. I have never touched it until a week ago, however I am proficient in Java. I'm currently working on this assignment in which a user will input a command and the necessary parameters in one line.

The requirements are as follows: The command must be entered correctly (add, sub, mul, div, col). There must exist the parameters to match the command (i.e. add needs two parameters, but col only needs one). Anything entered after the command and the parameters are to be cleared from the buffer.

An example would be that a user will input "add 13 12" and the sum will be printed on screen. Where I'm struggling with is with malformed data. I need to ensure that the user will input "add 13 12" and and not just "add 13" or "add a".

Currently, my code reads as follows.

```
int exit = 0;
do {
    //Error checking will be done here
    char command[3];
    int a, b;

    //Input Stream
    printf("Command: ");
    scanf("%s", command);


    if(strcmp(command, "add") == 0) {
        scanf("%d ", &a);
        if (!feof(stdin)) {
            scanf("%d", &b);
            Add(a, b);
        } else {
            printf("Requires second parameter\r\n");
        }

    } else if (strcmp(command, "sub") == 0) {
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        if(a > b) {
            Subtract(a, b);
        } else {
            printf("The first integer must be greater than the second integer\r\n");
        }
    } else if (strcmp(command, "mul") == 0) {
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        Multiply(a, b);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "div") == 0) {
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        if(b > 0 && (a > b)) {
            Divide(a, b);
        } else {
            printf("The denominator must not be 0 or greater than the numerator\r\n");
        }
    } else if (strcmp(command, "col") == 0) {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if (a > 0) {
            Collatz(a);
        } else {
            printf("Integer must be one or greater\r\n");
        }
    } else if (strcmp(command, "bye") == 0) {
        printf("bye");
        exit = 1;
    } else {
        printf("Incorrect command, please enter add, sub, mul, div, col, or bye.\r\n");
    }
} while(exit == 0);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: You have read [ask] and your question about a **specific** problem with a [mcve] is?

Comment: `char command[3];`  isn't large enough size.

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of params successfully read, so use that result to ensure you parsed all the inputs needed to add, sub, etc.